# Hiren's Boot PE, NVMe & RAID - a RAW deal

Tags: raid, data-recovery, partition-recovery, raw, hiren

On HP laptop Windows 11, I booted into Windows perfectly normally, then I rebooted into Hirens Boot PE, opened Aomei Backupper, did not do any action in that application, then I opened Disk Management, and the C partiton had become a RAW filesystem, all in the span of 2 minutes.

This is a new laptop 1TB NVMe, but there also is a small disk inside, in most disk utilities, it says it is 27GB, but in Aomei Partition Assistant, it says it is a 27Gb disk with a 1Tb filesystem, very strange. In linux, it says that the 27Gb internal disk is a RAID filesystem. I think it said it was an Intel Raid filesystem.

The UEFI had a very large amount of possible settings, literally many hundreds of settings, it was very customizable, a lot of security, very modern. A lot of Intel settings.

What caused Windows to be able to boot normally day after day, and then in 2 minutes become a RAW filesystem. Is it because Hirens Boot PE was created prior to most NVMe drivers? Perhaps opening the 2018 version of Aomei caused this? I saw a similar situation where years ago I booted a RAID PC with a linux and did literally nothing in there, rebooted, and then it broke the RAID Array and the PC was sent to Data Recovery lab. Very odd in both cases.

Comment: I take it that Windows doesn't boot any more? What is the exact model of the computer?